# easyautocomplete in material design

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to realize a html input field in material design.
For that I have the following code:

```css
   
/*
 * easy-autocomplete
 * jQuery plugin for autocompletion
 * 
 * @author Łukasz Pawełczak (http://github.com/pawelczak)
 * @version 1.3.5
 * Copyright  License: 
 */




 


.group { 
margin: 48px;
  position:relative; 
}
input {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
input:focus { outline:none; }



/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar { position:relative; display:block; width:300px; }
.bar:before, .bar:after  {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#5264AE; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .bar:before, input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://easyautocomplete.com/dist/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html> 
 <body>

    <div class="group">      
      <input id="acInput" type="text" required>
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

This works good. But now I would like to make an auto complete input field, which has the material design, too

For that I add a few lines of javascript

```
var options = {
   data: ["Max Mustermann","Peter Parr"],
};
$("#acInput").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

The result ist good, but not perfect. auto complete works, but without material design. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

When you apply `.easyAutocomplete(...)` your HTML structure get modified

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="easy-autocomplete" style="width: 315px;">
        <input id="acInput" type="text" required="" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="easy-autocomplete-container" id="eac-container-acInput">
            <ul style="display: none;">
                <li>
                    <div class="eac-item">Max Mustermann</div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="eac-item">Peter Parr</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

You'll need to update the css to match the new HTML structure.

Comment: But what I have to modify. the only thing which will be new added is the div easy-autocomplete container. but the input filed will stay the same ?

Comment: the tilde `~` css selector in your css is looking for siblings of INPUT that have a class 'bar' or 'highlight'. After applying `.easyAutocomplete(...)` those elements are no longer siblings